# Display single row with headers one column per line in bash

Tags: linux, awk, text-formatting

I want to display a single row from a large csv file with headers next to it using bash.

The file:

```
head1, head2, head3....
data1.1, data1.2, data1.3
data2.1, data2.2, data2.3
...
```

I want to see row 2 like this:

```
head1:  data2.1
head2:  data2.2
head3:  data2.3
```

I only dabble in awk, but pretty sure it could do this for me, but other suggestions welcome.
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In  `bash` you may try

```
paste <(sed 's/, /:\n/g; s/$/:/; q' file) <(sed -n '3 { s/, /\n/g; p; q }' file)
head1:  data2.1
head2:  data2.2
head3:  data2.3
```